# How do I extract a particular line from Json stdclass array?

Tags: php, json

ok this is an Api call

```
   $json_string = '"offices":
      [{"description": "Google Headquarters",
        "address1": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
        "address2": "",
        "zip_code": "",
        "city": "Mountain View",
        "state_code": "CA",
        "country_code": "USA",
        "latitude": 37.421972,
        "longitude": -122.084143},
       {"description": "Google Ann Arbor",
        "address1": "112 S. Main St.",
        "address2": "2nd Floor",
        "zip_code": "48104",
        "city": "Ann Arbor",
        "state_code": "MI",
        "country_code": "USA",
        "latitude": 42.280988,
        "longitude": -83.748882},
       {"description": "Google Atlanta",
        "address1": "10 10th Street NE",
        "address2": "Suite 600",
        "zip_code": "30309"';//more but trimming here.

$obj=json_decode($json_string);
foreach($obj->offices as $office) {
    echo $office->address1;

     }
```

This gives whole result on address1. but I need only content from first address1. how do I do this??

Comment: noticed nobodies explained why, you are looping through a list of objects which each have an address1 property, you need do loose the loop and just reference the first member as per galambalazs answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$obj->offices[0]->address1` should work.

Answer (score 4):

```
$offices  = $obj->offices;    // offices is a key of $obj
$first    = $offices[0];      // its value is an array, we want index 0
$address1 = $first->address1; // this is an object, we want it's address1 key
```